# jQuery status 200 ok error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a very special problem with jQuery ajax requests.

when a user is browsig various parts of the webpage, there are jquery get() calls to fetch some content.
The thing is that those requests stop working on random occasions.
When I check the request response in firebug, the request status is 200 OK, but the firebug request is colored as red as in there was an error, but there is no error message.

The response tab in firebug is empty.

The thing is that is I visit those urls normally, not thought ajax, the content is returned normally.

So if I restart the browser it's all good again,
I'm using jquery 1.7.1 and jquery.effects.core.js

Here's where I make the request:

```
$.get('abc', function(data) {
...
}).error(function(xhr, status, error) { alert("An AJAX error occured: " + status +     "\nError: " + error);});
```

The alert gets called when the problem occurs and the 'status' variable has value of 'error' and the 'error' variable is an empty string...

I really have no idea what could the problem. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried any other browsers?

Comment: Some code would be usefull... give at least a snippet that return the above error

Comment: yep. And the problem really occrurs randomly

Comment: There's definitely something "special" going on here.

Comment: crytal ball comments are most amazingly hilarious without doubt. But some actial help would be even better.

Comment: Would have liked this one to stay open. Having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to always catch errors and report them so you can find the problem without guessing what it may be:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '<url>',
    success : function (serverResponse) { ... },
    error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (typeof console == 'object' && typeof console.log == 'function') {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    }
});
```

This checks to make sure that `console.log` exists and is a function before trying to use it. If `console.log` exists then this will log the all the error information associated with the AJAX request.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax